# Maven project is not working fine , POM xml is incorrect & Cucumber is not recognised

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

My maven project was working fine , after adding few plugins for Jar files
MAven Project errors . JDK version is not identified 
Cucumber feature file displays error as "mismatched input '\n' expecting 'Feature:'"

Maven Project displays some black * symbol on src, test, folders

[Maven project Folder error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8kE8.png)

[Cucumber Feature Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGBPB.png)

POM.XML:

```
             <name>maven-automation_test_suite</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.mylyn.docs</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.24</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Without some code you're making us guess.

Comment: <plugins>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.7.0</version>
       <configuration>
         <source>1.8</source>
         <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
        </plugins>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>

Comment: Please edit your post and add code.  Include the errors you're getting.

Comment: @stdunbar ,  I cant paste  XML , i commented a part of  POM.XMl , when I try to create a new Feature  file  am getting error as mismatched input '\n' expecting 'Feature:'

Comment: Please provide more insight into your Problem. From what I have read this far, I would say that there is a problem in your own Pom syntax. Without error messages and the full Pom this is kind hard to tell. You will not get any good feedback with a question like this. Your Pom snippet Looks like you did screw up the plugin config.

Comment: @triplem , I have added POMXML , & image for error , Issue 1. I cannot create new feature files - Error as "mismatched input '\n' expecting 'Feature:'" Issue2: I can see some images in Maven fodler structure  maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile  - Failes for some Array String as <> diamond operator is not supported in -source

Comment: @triplem  , Attached full POM , can u help me , I feel I messed up POM & JDK version as lot , This is my current JDK C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Answer (score 0):

Black icon is just symbol to tell that you have some changes in your branch which are either staged or partially staged. Nothing for you to worry about.

staged: Any tracked file with changes that are already included in the index.

partially-staged: Any tracked file with changes, where some changes are already included in the index,  and others that are not yet added.

Cucumber error can't be solved unless you show us the full feature file.
I think it's a spacing issue.
It happens to me sometimes if I do something like
`Feature :` instead of `Feature:`

Regarding run failure or project build failure, cannot comment unless you show me the full pom file.

Comment: I cannot resolve that Cucumber  issue, its not spacing issue , even when I create a new Cucumber feature , format is affected alot. Even though feature file errors,  I was able to create new feature & execute them

Comment: @Gayathri Nothing can be confirmed unless u show the feature file. It can also be due to the cucumber editor plugin which u r using.